# Как загрузить нужный контент в зависимости от ширины экрана?

Tags: javascript, html, адаптивная-верстка

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать загрузку определенного контента в зависимости от ширины экрана клиента?
Имеется сайт на бутстрапе, при мобильной версии появляется бургер, все по классике бутстрапа, но есть еще одна идея, десктопнный логотип по верстке находится над навбаром, и при загрузки мобильной версии должен убираться… я реализовал это на jq и все равно при слабом интернете получаю моргание этого логотипа, который исчезает с задержкой. Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли как нибудь вообще до начала загрузки страницы понять размер экрана пользователя, чтобы выдать ему нужный контент? Если да, то как? Использую стандартную связку бутстрапа и jq.

Comment: Ну и не используйте jquery для этого, просто допустим мобилка начинается с 767px - @media (max-width: 767px) {.logo {display: none;}} .logo - это типо логотип.

Comment: Или у bootstrap есть уже готовый класс для этого - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/

Comment: Ооо спасибо))) походу пора отдохнуть очевидное решение не сделал)))